# How to update the object with key and value as an array in javascript,typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an object named dropdowns,object with key value pair.I want to update the object named dropdowns.How to update the object.Please help me.

```
dropdowns: any = {};

dropdowns={
           clientCode: ["ALDR","NIKE"], 
           carrierCode: ["XYZ","ABC","DEF","GHI"], 
           invoiceCount: [123,456,789]
          }
```

I wank to make clientCode:["LMN","OPQ","RST","UVW"]
How can I update the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdowns.clientCode = ["LMN","OPQ","RST","UVW"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access your dropdown object using "."(dot) operator and then select the key which you want to update as you said "clientCode" then do as :

```
//objectname.key = newvalue; -- syntax
dropdown.clientCode = ["LMN","OPQ","RST","UVW"];
```